# Using DOM elements as keys to javascript map

Tags: javascript

I am trying to associate some "private" data with DOM elements.  Rather than adding that data to the DOM element itself (I'd like to avoid changing the DOM element), I have a separate data object that I want to use as a map.

Rather than:

```
document.GetElementById('someElementId').privateData = {};
```

I want to do

```
internalPrivateDataMap[document.GetElementById('someElementId')].privateData = {};
```

Not all the elements have an id field, and some are created dynamically, so I can't use the id as the key.

This works fine for most elements, but for "a" elements, the key being used seems to be the href of the element, I think because the DOM defines a toString() function for a elements.

The result of this is that if I have two "a" elements with the same href, they are sharing privateData, which I don't want.

My current workaround is to generate an internal uniqueID I can use as a key, but that requires me to modify the DOM element, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: *"This works fine for most elements"* It does? I would think you'd be getting a generic key `[object HTMLDivElement]` that way. ...but yes, an anchor will give its `href` as the `.toString()` value.

Comment: You have to wait for *ES.Next*. *WeakMaps* will allow that.

Comment: No, extending the DOM element with a UID is just they way to go. Without WeakMaps, you can't get an identifying key for your dataMap from elements other than by this.

Comment: @user1689607 - I should have said, "This works fine for most elements in my application".  After looking closely, though, you're right.  All elements have the same problem (sharing keys), it just causes a bug with a elements.  That helped clarify what is going on for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you noticed, this doesn't work reliably and I know no way to make it work without either giving every element a (generated) ID or at least assign a unique ID to a new custom element field; DOM nodes simply don't have the necessary properties to work as keys in a map.

So you really have these solutions left:

- Assign each element a generated ID unless it already has one
- Assign a unique ID to a new private field. That way, you can keep the memory impact per DOM node small and still keep your private data in a different place. Don't forget that you need to clean the private data somehow when the DOM elements are deleted.
- Use something like jQuery which has `element.data()` to read and put private data into a DOM element
- Use your own `element.privateData = {};` Note that you still need cleanup for event handlers which keep references to the element or you will have unexpected memory leaks.

Comment: Assuming each element can't have an ID, I'd just use the last one. By far the simplest.

Comment: @user1689607: This can cause problems like memory leaks. Also, you can't have two values for the same key, i.e. if you have two frameworks which try to save private values, they could interfere with each other.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Yes, you'd need a unique key, but so would the same with the UID option. And yes, there could be memory leaks, but it's the same with the UID option.

Comment: I mean there would be a memory leak if you'd put an event handler which has a reference to the element into `element.privateData`

Comment: Why wouldn't you have the same leak if the same handler is stored in a cache, and looked up via the UID?

Comment: If you don't clean the cache, you have lots of leaks - keeping the data separate from the DOM element means you don't get any automatic cleanup. It's obvious that you need to do this yourself. But if an event handler keeps a reference to the element, you get an unexpected memory leaks.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Yeah, and that's my main point. Either way, to be safe, you'd need some manual intervention *(until WeakMaps are available)*. But with the separate cache, you'll *always* have leaks if things aren't cleaned up, but with a direct assignment most modern browsers should take care of things if you forget *(except for those closure leaks you described)*. Just seems to me that more can go wrong with the UID approach.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's ok with an inefficient solution, you could create a custom map class that leverages [node equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode). Here's the basic idea, extend as needed:

```
// Map that has dom elements as keys. Note: O(N) lookup, insertion and deletion
class ElementMap {
  constructor() {
    this.pairs = [];
  }

  set(element, value) {
    const pair = this.pairs.find(p => p.element === element);
    if (pair) {
      pair.value = value;
    } else {
      this.pairs.push({ element, value });
    }
  }

  get(element) {
    return this.pairs.find(p => p.element === element)?.value || null;
  }

  delete(element) {
    const idx = this.pairs.findIndex(p => p.element === element);
    if (idx >= 0) {
      this.pairs = [...this.pairs.slice(0, idx), ...this.pairs.slice(idx + 1)];
    }
  }
}
```